# Как добавить для всех переменных с типом Array новый метод?

Tags: javascript

Этот вопрос прозвучал на собеседовании.
Сперва я подумал воспользоваться Array.prototype.push(), но это не правильно так как добавляет элемент(ы).
Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Ну я думаю вы были почти правы. Насколько я помню можно как-то так:

```
Array.prototype.newfunc = function() {
 alert(this)
}

const ar = [1,2,3,4]
ar.newfunc() // [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь